# Override Listview.Columns.Add(string)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listview

Ive got a custom listview class like this one:

```
class ListTreeView : ListView
{
    //some stuff
}
```

Is there a way to override `columns.add(string text);` like i can do with Refresh()

```
public override void Refresh()
{
    //some stuff
}
```

Comment: I think you're out of luck as ListView.Columns is read-only. So you can not assign a custom ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection to it.

Comment: Why do you need to overwrite it?

Comment: i wanted to ++ the column counter every time when a new column were added. i can do it other ways, but thought with override would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to override Columns.Add(string text); like i can do with Refresh()

'No'

If a method is declared `Virtual`, then `Yes`. But unfortunately in your case its a `No` because `ColumnHeaderCollection` can't be overridden.

Comment: could you please be more specific? Do you mean `VirtualMode = true;` ? And it's nice that its possible to do, but how?

Comment: He means if the Add method is declared as virtual. But it doesn't make sense, since you can't override the ColumnHeaderCollection.